# Rails Nested Resources with custom method not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, nested

I want to a "cancel" method for user projects that instead of removing the record, it updates the status to "cancelled", stores the last status before the cancellation and records a reason (input) from the user.

I have controllers for user (devise) and projects which are nested. The RESTful actions seem to all work fine, but the cancel option doesn't and I can't figure it out!

Here is my `routes.rb`

```
 devise_for :users

 resources :users do
  resources :projects do
    get "cancel" => 'projects#cancel'
    post "cancel" => 'projects#cancel_save'
  end
end
```

When I run `rake routes`

```
             user_project_cancel GET    /users/:user_id/projects/:project_id/cancel(.:format) projects#cancel
                                 POST   /users/:user_id/projects/:project_id/cancel(.:format) projects#cancel_save
                   user_projects GET    /users/:user_id/projects(.:format)                    projects#index
                                 POST   /users/:user_id/projects(.:format)                    projects#create
                new_user_project GET    /users/:user_id/projects/new(.:format)                projects#new
               edit_user_project GET    /users/:user_id/projects/:id/edit(.:format)           projects#edit
                    user_project GET    /users/:user_id/projects/:id(.:format)                projects#show
                                 PATCH  /users/:user_id/projects/:id(.:format)                projects#update
                                 PUT    /users/:user_id/projects/:id(.:format)                projects#update
                                 DELETE /users/:user_id/projects/:id(.:format)                projects#destroy
```

My `projects_controller.rb` (I included the whole thing just in case)

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :deny_to_visitors
before_action :correct_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :cancel, :cancel_save]
before_action :set_current_status, only: [:cancel, :cancel_save]

def index
  @projects = Project.all.order(id: :asc)
end

def show
end

def new
  @project = current_user.projects.new
  @budgets = Budget.all
end

def edit
end

def create
  @project = current_user.projects.new(project_params)
  @project.project_status_id = 1
  if @project.save
    redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Your project is being reviewed. We will be in contact soon!'
    AdminMailer.new_project_email(current_user, @project).deliver_now
  else
    render :new
  end
end 

def update
  if @project.update(project_params)
    if admin_signed_in?
      redirect_to admin_projects_list_path, notice: 'Project was successfully updated.'
    else
      redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Project was successfully updated.'
    end
  else
    render :edit
  end
end

def destroy
  @project.destroy
  redirect_to projects_url, notice: 'Project was successfully destroyed.'
end

def cancel
end

def cancel_save
  @project.cancel_reason.update(:project_id, :last_status_id, :comment)
  @project.update_attribute(:project_status_id, 10)

  redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Project has been successfully cancelled.'
end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def deny_to_visitors
    redirect_to root_path unless user_signed_in? or admin_signed_in?
  end

def correct_user
  if admin_signed_in?
    @project = Project.find_by(id: params[:id])
  else
    @project = current_user.projects.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end
  redirect_to user_projects_path, notice: "You are not authorised to view this project" if @project.nil?
  end

def set_current_status
  @current_status = current_user.projects.find_by(id: params[:id]).project_status_id
end

def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:user_id, :project_type_id, :name, :industry_id, :description, :budget_id, :project_status_id, feature_ids:[], addon_ids:[])
end

end
```

Links in my view

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_project_path(current_user, project) %>
<%= link_to 'Cancel', user_project_cancel_path(current_user, project) %>
```

I have a super simple page for `cancel.html.erb` at the moment that doesn't even have the form yet until I figure out what's going wrong.

```
<h1>Cancel</h1>
<p><%= @project.name %></p>
```

**UPDATED**

When I click on the link to cancel a project, I get this in the rails server console log:

```
    Started GET "/users/1/projects/3/cancel" for ::1 at 2016-09-26 17:21:50 +0200
    Processing by ProjectsController#cancel as HTML
    Parameters: {"user_id"=>"1", "project_id"=>"3"}
    User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
    Project Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."user_id" = $1 AND "projects"."id" IS NULL LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
    Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/1/projects
    Filter chain halted as :correct_user rendered or redirected
    Completed 302 Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
```

When it loads the project above, it loads `AND "projects"."id" IS NULL LIMIT $2` - Why is the value `NULL` when it's clearly passing in the `project_id` of `3`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this was a little weird. I fixed it, by doing the following:

In `routes.rb` I changed the line:

```
get "cancel" => 'projects#cancel'
```

to

```
get "cancel", :on => :member
```

This changed my routing. So when I `rake routes`, my route now looked like this:

```
cancel_user_project GET    /users/:user_id/projects/:id/cancel(.:format)   projects#cancel
```

Which is now consistent with the RESTful pathing (eg: for edit, the path is edit_user_project). I then updated my link as follows:

Old Link

```
<%= link_to 'Cancel', user_project_cancel_path(current_user, project) %>
```

New Link

```
<%= link_to 'Cancel', cancel_user_project_path(current_user, project) %>
```

And now it works. Still not entirely sure why it wasn't happy with the custom action in the routing, but that was apparently the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the output of following associations?

> current_user.projects

Comment: Sorry I am still learning rails - what's the best way to check the output of that association?

Comment: As a quick test, I changed the `index` method as follows. Instead of using : `@projects = Project.all.order(id: :asc)`, I used `@projects = current_user.projects` and I get the same result on the index page. It lists all of the users projects

Comment: You can use rails console or debugg via pry gem. So if you are using rails console the just type ...User.find(id).projects...here pass the id of user which is the current user id. Also check the the associations between User class and Project class. As per your code it should be User has_many projects and Project belongs_to user. Let me know what exactly you need to do with admin_signed_in? condition.

Comment: Ok so using the User.find(id).projects returns all of the correct projects for the selected user. The User and Project associations are correct (User has_many :projects, and Projects belongs_to :user). Regarding the admin_signed_in? -> I have a second devise controller for an admin account that I'm working with, but don't need to worry about that for now.

Comment: I've updated the question above to show the console log for when I click on the "cancel" link

Comment: It was because the route "/users/:user_id/projects/:project_id/cancel" which is being using :project_id while in thise code snippet you are using :id - "@project = current_user.projects.find_by(id: params[:id])"